# Fire an action after all actions in redux-observable epic

Tags: angular, rxjs, redux-observable

I want to fire an action after all actions happened. Here is my code:

```
 public fetchCategories(action$: Observable<ICategoryAction>, store: Store<IAppState>) {
    return action$.pipe(
      ofType(CategoryActionType.FETCH_CATEGORIES),
      switchMap((action) => {
         return this._categoryService.list(action.payload)
      }),
      flatMap(data => [
        this._categoryAction.addCategories(new Categories(data)),
      ])
    ).catch((error) => {
      return Observable.of(this._commonAction.showError(error));
    })
    .concat(Observable.of(this._commonAction.hideLoading())); // <<== Doesn't work   
   }
```

I want to hide loading after success or error in catch. But it doesn't `concat` with last actions. I can see everything work well until `addCategories()`.

However it doesn't call `concat`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have won't work because `concat` subscribes to its inner Observable only after the source Observable completes. `action$` is in fact a Subject that never completes (this would mean it can't emit any more actions). The same case is with the `catch` you have.

This largely depends on what the structure of your actions is but you can do something as the following:

```
action$.pipe(
  ofType(CategoryActionType.FETCH_CATEGORIES),
    switchMap((action) => this._categoryService.list(action.payload)
      .pipe(
        catchError(() => of(this._commonAction.showError(error)))
      ),
    }),
    mergeMap(data => [
      this._categoryAction.addCategories(new Categories(data)),
      of(this._commonAction.hideLoading()),
    ])
```

I'm actually guessing what your code should do because I don't know what `.addCategories` returns. `mergeMap` on an array will just flattens it which is probably wanted to do (but with one array item you could use just `map`)?

Btw be aware that you're mixing pipable and prototype operators: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/pipeable-operators.md

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot.It's work well. However it can not catch the error. Do you have any idea?

Comment: It catches only errors from `this._categoryService.list` so I don't know where the error happens in your code.

Comment: I have put the ` return Observable.throw('test');` inside the `this._categoryService.list` function for test but it doesn't work!